# How to get the URL of the locally installed KDB database

Tags: java, sql, database, jdbc, kdb

I have a KDB database in my machine. How should I get the URL of the database ? Actually I want to access the database using Java (JDBC), therefore I need its URL.

Answer (score 3):

If you start your database instance with a listening port (-p xxxx on command line or \p xxxx in session), then your URL will be hostname:port.

See http://code.kx.com/q/interfaces/java-client-for-q/ and http://code.kx.com/q/cookbook/ipc/ for a good introduction.